# How do I breed Villagers in Minecraft for Xbox 360?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I've made a small village (an 'apartment block' within a fenced off area). The buildings have walls, doors (4 per room) and a roof. Each room has a torch. I've managed to corral 5 villagers. 3 I have left to do what they want in the 'pen' and 2 I have put in a room together. I have then left to do other things to, in affect, give them privacy ;).

However, They never seem to breed, I haven't seen one baby villager the whole time! What am I doing wrong? is there a setting I need?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Breeding) on Villagers and how they breed, along with structural requirements, which I believe you met, they also have to be "willing" in a way similar to when you feed cows wheat.

You can make them willing by trading with them (they give off green particle effects when they are made willing). They will not likely immediately seek out a mate however, so you should give them some more privacy after trading.

Answer (score 0):

If you have village spawn eggs, spawn villagers pointing your cursor at a villager, and a baby will be born.

Comment: don't have spawn eggs and not sure where I can get them :(

Comment: If you have cheats enabled, you can use `/give` but other than that I don't think you can get spawn eggs in survival.