# Minecraft Villager Breeding

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing xbox one and my villagers are not breeding. I am pretty sure I saw green sparkles over their heads and idk what that means, but I haven’t seen red hearts over their heads. I have a structure made with a ton of beds. Also, doors above the ceiling and those doors are smooshed together by another layer of blocks on top. There is a ton of light, but no red hearts. I’ve been waiting for about 20 minutes.

Comment: If you could provide a screenshot of your build, that would be very helpful

Comment: You also need to give them food and trade with them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren’t my villagers breeding?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/325091/why-aren-t-my-villagers-breeding) or [How do I breed Villagers in Minecraft for Xbox 360?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/295936/4797)

Answer (score 0):

Villagers require to be fed in both editions of the game, in order for them to become willing to breed. The best way to do this is to feed them bread, as this is most efficient, however carrots, potatoes and beetroot will also work. Both the villagers need at least 12 of the veggies, or 3 bread to start breeding, but it doesn't hurt to give them a bit more.

Comment: I have fed them countless carrots and bread and beetroot and potatoes haha still nothing. I also destroyed both villages within a 150 block radius of my village and still nothing... I cured another 2 zombie villagers so I have 4 and no hearts over any of them.